# Creating a server-client based JAVA game for guessing a number

Tags: java

So I started to create a basic JAVA game for guessing a number. In the server jFrame I type the number to guess (into a jTextField), click the OK button and then the server starts. The number must have 4 digits. The client then types a four digit number into a jTextField and clicks OK. If he guesses a digit on the right position the server returns 0 to the client. If he guesses a digit but on the wrong position then the server returns X. Example: The number to guess is 1356. The client sends the number 1643. Then the server would return 0XX (the digit 1 is on the right position, the digits 6 and 3 are on the wrong positions).

This is what I have on the client side:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Socket cs = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666);
    final DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
    final Client client1 = new Client();



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            client1.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    client1.jTextArea1.append("\n You are connected");

    while (true) {
        if (nr==1){
            os.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
            nr=0;
        }

    }


}
```

When the button ok on the client jFrame is clicked after I type the alleged number, the variable nr becomes 1:

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    nr=1;
    jTextArea1.append("\n You have entered the number "+Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));


}
```

The thing is that even if I click on the OK button and the variable nr becomes 1, the client won't send the number to the server. What seems to be the issue that's causing this?

I won't provide the code for the server as it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried The Netty Project? I think is the best framework to build client/server applications...

Comment: No. This is just a boring college assignment in which I got to use sockets. It might be something wrong with Netbeans as I recently learned that my game works on other systems

Comment: ah ok, welcome to StackOverflow anyway

Comment: I found the issue myself. I added a Thread.sleep(10) in the loop and now it works.

Comment: Please rephrase your solution as an answer to your question (or delete your question if you really think it won't be useful for other StackOverflow users).